# bot.telegram.getChat does not return the message of a specific user

Tags: telegram-bot, telegraf

I am trying to setup my bot so that it will 'listen' to a specific user and print out any incoming message.

I have already setup a bot in telegram using BotFather. This is what I have so far

```
const { Telegraf } = require('telegraf')
const bot = new Telegraf('my_bot_token_here');

bot.telegram.getChat(Chat_Id).then(function(chat) {
  console.log('chat info', chat);
});
```

The object does not contain the user message.

Any advice on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely.  You need to check the 'from' field in the message before executing your logic.

[Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message)

Comment: I have updated my question, not sure how to implement that :(

Comment: Sorry, I cannot teach you the telegram API.  There are some good tutorials available!  Maybe try this one: https://www.section.io/engineering-education/telegram-bot-in-nodejs/

Comment: HAHA I already saw that. Did not really help